# Data forwarding server

Tags: c#, java, android, windows, portforwarding

I have the app for Android and another app for PC, both were written by me. Android app connects to the PC app, and the PC app sends data (in realtime) to the smartphone.

The problem is: if the PC is connected to the mobile wireless network, I can't get its address, so I can't connect my Android app to the PC.

So, is there some simple application (for Windows), that I can use as a server for data forwarding. PC and mobile App will be connected to this server (launched on the station with the static address), and the server will just forward data from one app to another?

Or maybe there are good tutorials for creating such kind of server on C#/Java?

Comment: Which communication protocol do you use?

Comment: TCP. I works good, when mobile app connects directly to the PC. But I am going to use UDP to decrease latency.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a third pc (a server) that acts as a bridge for Android and PC. I wrote a web service in .NET for a virtual server on the internet. Both Android and PC know the ip address (or the domain name) of the server.

The PC talk to server using .NET native web service call, the Android uses ksoap.

For more infomration about ksoap for android look here:

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

**EDIT:**
I suppose you can have the web server in the pc but you need to configure your modem to forward specific ports to the pc. But if you have no static ip address you need to reconfigure the ip address on Android device everytime your modem is rebooted (or switched off/on). You can also try to use dynamic dns services...

Comment: The solution must be simple for the PC user. User just starts the app and push "connect", and then all magic happens on the server side, server waits for the connection from mobile app and then forwards data. I have created some kind of such server, but it works not very good) So, I need a complete server unit (library, application), or a tutorial for creating it.

Comment: Hmmm I wrote my own server and it works fine. Did you use web services in your server?

Comment: I wrote it on Java, but I am going to do it on C#. Just seeking for the correct way for handling disconnections, async recieving/sending.

Comment: Just curious: did you used a server with a fixed ip? Did you bought a virtual server or something else?

Comment: Yeap, it has fixed ip. The problem is in correct way of handling disconnections, async data forwarding.

Comment: So I suppose you arent using soap web services. I've another server that act as relay server for a PC and the Android app. And yes, disconnections and data forwarding is hell.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: 
 http://whiletrue.blog.com/2013/07/11/smartphone-as-pc-controller/

I've made this with Muzzley. Basically, you already have most of the work done if you integrate with it.
(disclaimer: i work for this project)

**On the PC side**, you can use the lib to include in you pc app in several languages:

- (java) http://www.muzzley.com/documentation/libraries/java.html
- (.NET) http://www.muzzley.com/documentation/libraries/dotnet.html
- (nodejs) http://www.muzzley.com/documentation/libraries/nodejs.html

**On the smartphone side**, you can use any of the existent widgets (virtual interfaces):

- http://www.muzzley.com/documentation/widgets.html

or eventually make your own:

- http://www.muzzley.com/documentation/widgets/webview.html

**Example:**

You can pull from github several examples here:

- https://github.com/muzzley/muzzley-demos/

(check the the webview example)

I hope it helps.